# Method to laying wieghted items on a grid

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, matrices, vectors

I am trying to come up with a way to evenly lay items out on a grid of a fixed size 6 x 4 ( 24 positions ) this would be similar to a pigeonhole problem.

To make this easier I will assign color value to a marble rather than a number.

```
6 - red 
1 - orange
10 - yellow
2 - green 
2 - white 
2 - black
4 - purple
```

Place a marble in each pigeonhole such that:

a) no two of the same colors are touching one another,top, bottom, left or right.

b) marbles with the highest quantities are used first.

*Thoughts:*
I see that this would probably be well suited to some type of matrix layout. Where each value is a "weight", a vector field or a heat map; some kind of tree or binning. I am not sure how to further proceed.

My apologies if this is not the right place to ask,I am unsure how to classify or approach this problem.

Comment: This is a good place, but you have to work on your question.  Are you looking for one layout that meets the requirement in a?  The number of layouts?  I don't understand what you mean by using some marbles first.  With disparate numbers of marbles of each color, counting the number of patterns will probably need computer enumeration-there doesn't seem and easy way to count the number of legal positions to me.

Comment: Oh yea I was not expecting to do this by hand or anything. While it would be interesting to create and count the possible layouts one layout is enough.

Comment: Doing one by hand would be pretty easy.  You are right to start with a blank grid and fill in the ones you have a lot of first.

Comment: What type of algorithmic process would this fall under if one where to write a computer program to solve different solutions?

Comment: You would usually make a backtracking program.  You put a yellow marble in the first square, then find the next square that can accept a yellow, and so on until the yellows are placed.  Now place the rest of the marbles.  If you succeed, count the pattern and go back and change the last choice you made.  You can speed it up by noting that the three pairs are equivalent and deciding always to place a green before the first white or black and white before black, then multiplying by 6.  By the way, you have 25 marbles listed, so they won't fit in $4 \times 6$

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get an arrangement by hand is to group the marbles into two groups of twelve, say the yellow+green and everything else.  We can make an arrangement of the two groups that meets your requirement a by doing a checkerboard.  There are twelve light squares and twelve dark squares.  Now distribute the yellow+green any way you like on the (say) light squares and all the rest on the dark squares.